# How to correct strange margin error in fixed-column of HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I have been following the information I could gather (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754740/html-table-with-fixed-first-column)) and built an HTML table, that has its first column fixed, with CSS only. 
Unfortunately the fixed column is positioning itself a good few pixels lower than the rest of the content and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the code: [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/g77nLu5w/10/). What am I doing wrong?

Tried the following things:

- Changed cell size, margin, padding and border settings
- Replaced `position: absolute` with `float: left`
- Tried placing the scrolling on other element
- Added/removed content
- `margin-top: -16px;` does not fix the problem, because the distance changes with the height of the cells

```css
.table 
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid grey; 
  display: table;
}

.tr
{
  display: table-row;
}

.th
{
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid grey;   
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.td 
{
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid grey;   
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:0;
}

.wrapper 
{ 
  overflow-x:scroll;  
  margin-left:100px; 
  overflow-y:visible;  
}

.wrapper-outer
{ 
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.fixed {
  position:absolute; 
  width:100px; 
  left:0;
  top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper-outer>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="th fixed">Fixed 1</div>
            <div class="th">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
            <div class="th">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="th">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 1</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 2</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 3</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 4</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 5</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another solution, I guess, would be to make 2 tables - 1 with just the left most "fixed" column, and the the other right next to it with all the other content.

Comment: Looks like this will be my solution in the end. Still, I wish to know where that top distance originates from.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.th.fixed {
    top: 0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s482epd3/)

(Working in Chrome - doesn't look right in FireFox)

Comment: And what about rest of `.td.fixed`?

Comment: The rest look fine, so... nothing?

Comment: Well, on Firefox I see gap between first row and second

Comment: @Justinas what about them? The issue just required fixing the first row of the first column

Comment: Yeah, just realized that also.

Comment: @porjolovsky *the fixed **column** is positioning*

Answer (score 1):

I have added `margin-top` for fixed `td` and it worked

http://jsfiddle.net/g77nLu5w/11/

Comment: Unfortunately the 16px distance changes with the height of the cells so it cannot be hard-coded.

Comment: replace it with margin-top:-5%;

Answer (score 0):

Apply `.fixed {margin-top: -16px}`

```css
.table 
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid grey; 
  display: table;
}

.tr
{
  display: table-row;
}

.th
{
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid grey;   
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.td 
{
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid grey;   
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:0;
}

.wrapper 
{ 
  overflow-x:scroll;  
  margin-left:100px; 
  overflow-y:visible;  
}

.wrapper-outer
{ 
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.fixed {
  position:absolute; 
  width:100px; 
  left:0;
  top:auto;
  margin-top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper-outer>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="th fixed">Fixed 1</div>
            <div class="th">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
            <div class="th">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="th">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 1</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 2</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 3</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 4</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 5</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td fixed">Fixed 6</div>
            <div class="td">Lorem</div>
            <div class="td">Ipsum</div>
            <div class="td">Sator</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks really messed up in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Removing `position: absolute` from the `.fixed` css definition aligned the cells correctly for me, but you will have to play with the wrapper to get the table to correct width.

Absolute positioning is good for some things, but rarely good for creating tables.

Comment: The absolute positioning is the key to the whole thing, but let me try and find another approach. Already tried floating, not much left to try